separating strings in stringr when a number is followed immediately by a letter
I am not even sure I am thinking about this problem in the correct way, but I have some strings that I need to either separate into separate columns when a number is followed immediately by a letter, or delete the number and the letter combinations that are immediate next to each other - either solution would be acceptable.
Short example data
num_lets<-c("89c24c", "1234c5r78", "78", "1b23456c9", "1c2b4567c890")

I have tried things like "(?=[0-9])(?<=[a-z])" but this will separate "89c24c" into "89c" and "24c", when actually I want "8", "9c", "2", "4c". The letter is always associated with the number that immediately precedes it.
So ideally at the end I would like to have something that looks like this:
num_clean
82
12378
78
23459
456890

But separating the strings into several columns would also be fine whereby "1234c5r78" became 4 separate columns containing
"123", "4c", "5r", "78"
Many thanks in advance for any helpful suggests.

Try: gsub("[0-9][a-z]", "", num_lets).

Show your code please. Looks like you are using stringr::str_split?

Try stringr::str_extract_all(num_lets, "\\d[a-z]|\\d+(?=\\d[a-z]|$)")

Thanks Edward for the initial comment before the edit- I haven't tried gsub, but I imagine it is similar. It really was that simple. I ended up using str_replace_all(x$num_lets, c("[0-9][a-z]" = ""))

That's the stringr equivalent of gsub. I use base R functions whenever possible. In this case, there doesn't appear to be any justification for using stringr.
